# JQuery definition added in TypeScript code but it's not becoming part of transcompiled JS file

Tags: jquery, typescript, typescript-typings

I learnt that if I install and import TypeScript libraries, they will be compiled to JS and included in the JS build output but that is not the case with below script and I don't know why.

**main.ts**

```
/// <reference path="../typings/globals/jquery/index.d.ts" />
var data  = "Hello Tahir";
$("div").text(data);
```

Above code produces no errors and trans-compiles to

**main.js**

```
/// <reference path="../typings/globals/jquery/index.d.ts" />
var data = "Hello Tahir";
$("div").text(data);
//# sourceMappingURL=main.js.map
```

As you can see jQuery library is not part of final output and hence my code produces below error in browser's console

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined

For me the only way to resolve this issue is to add jquery to header of my template file like

```
<script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

But I believe this is not the proper way to do the stuff, there must be something that I am missing.

Need guidance, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.d.ts` files contain the defintions of the types of an external library; they are not the same as the external library itself. The typings are dropped when transpiling your TypeScript code into JavaScript, because JavaScript doesn't have explicit typing. As a consequence, the `.d.ts` file has no use in the transpiled code. It is just there to enable the TypeScript transpiler to do type checking for the external library.

To solve your problem, you have to copy the JQuery file you are using to your own `scripts` folder (or whatever folder your scripts go) and you have to reference this script file in your HTML header.